# file input from http (url) in melt plugin

Tags: ffmpeg, melt, melt-framework

I'm using [MELT](https://www.mltframework.org/docs/melt/) plugin for generating crossfade animation using series of images.

I found the corssfade animation script from [here](https://superuser.com/a/834035).

and the script is

```
melt -verbose \
-profile atsc_720p_25 \
001.png out=50 \
002.png out=75 -mix 25 -mixer luma \
003.png out=75 -mix 25 -mixer luma \
004.png out=75 -mix 25 -mixer luma \
005.png out=75 -mix 25 -mixer luma \
-consumer avformat:output.mp4 vcodec=libx264 an=1
```

But instead of providing file from local path, I want to use `http` url like

```
melt -verbose \
-profile atsc_720p_25 \
http://example.com/image1.jpg out=50 \
http://example.com/image2.jpg out=75 -mix 25 -mixer luma \
http://example.com/image3.jpg out=75 -mix 25 -mixer luma \
http://example.com/image4.jpg out=75 -mix 25 -mixer luma \
http://example.com/image5.jpg out=75 -mix 25 -mixer luma \
-consumer avformat:output.mp4 vcodec=libx264 an=1
```

But it gives

```
No LADSPA plugins were found!

Check your LADSPA_PATH environment variable.
```

and full output is

```
No LADSPA plugins were found!

Check your LADSPA_PATH environment variable.
[mjpeg @ 0x168a320] Changeing bps to 8
[mjpeg @ 0x12725a0] Changeing bps to 8
[mjpeg @ 0x1691120] Changeing bps to 8
[mjpeg @ 0x1bc5ac0] Changeing bps to 8
[mjpeg @ 0x1907ae0] Changeing bps to 8
[mjpeg @ 0x1d09a20] Changeing bps to 8
[mjpeg @ 0x13a2b00] Changeing bps to 8
[mjpeg @ 0x1e4e6e0] Changeing bps to 8
[mjpeg @ 0x1d0b8c0] Changeing bps to 8
[mjpeg @ 0x1d190c0] Changeing bps to 8
+-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+
|1=-10| |2= -5| |3= -2| |4= -1| |5=  0| |6=  1| |7=  2| |8=  5| |9= 10|
+-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|               H = back 1 minute,  L = forward 1 minute              |
|                 h = previous frame,  l = next frame                 |
|           g = start of clip, j = next clip, k = previous clip       |
|                0 = restart, q = quit, space = play                  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
[libx264 @ 0x7f7f980c7aa0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x7f7f980c7aa0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x7f7f980c7aa0] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x7f7f980c7aa0] 264 - core 148 r2643 5c65704 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[mjpeg @ 0x7f7f88433200] Changeing bps to 8
[mjpeg @ 0x7f7f88832980] Changeing bps to 8
[mjpeg @ 0x7f7f88052ac0] Changeing bps to 8
[mjpeg @ 0x7f7f88c5abe0] Changeing bps to 8
[mjpeg @ 0x7f7f88bdd560] Changeing bps to 8
[mjpeg @ 0x7f7f88beb2a0] Changeing bps to 8
[mjpeg @ 0x7f7f88c838a0] Changeing bps to 8
[mjpeg @ 0x7f7f894a1100] Changeing bps to 8
[mjpeg @ 0x7f7f88b6a3a0] Changeing bps to 8
[mjpeg @ 0x7f7f88b78840] Changeing bps to 8
[swscaler @ 0x7f7f88c5f740] YUV color matrix differs for YUV->YUV, using intermediate RGB to convert
[swscaler @ 0x7f7f88c5f740] YUV color matrix differs for YUV->YUV, using intermediate RGB to convert
[swscaler @ 0x7f7f898cc980] Warning: data is not aligned! This can lead to a speedloss
[swscaler @ 0x7f7f88c5f740] YUV color matrix differs for YUV->YUV, using intermediate RGB to convert
[swscaler @ 0x7f7f88c5f740] YUV color matrix differs for YUV->YUV, using intermediate RGB to convert
[swscaler @ 0x7f7f88c5f740] YUV color matrix differs for YUV->YUV, using intermediate RGB to convert
[mjpeg @ 0x7f7f89ff25a0] Changeing bps to 8
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Also, the generated video file is broken

**How can I provide http input?**